# GooglePlaceAPI error: -6 in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, google-places-api

after working with autocomplete UI Control https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/ i got error in XCODE console when i am going to search in search bar that Google provide.

I have use Google Maps frameworks with use of pods.

Error :

> error : -6
>   Set accountToAuthorizerBlock to be able to send authorized requests.

Answer (score 1):

I'm an engineer on the Places API for iOS team. This is an internal log message that was printed by mistake. It shouldn't actually affect the functionality of your app and it's fine to ignore it.